# Div ignoring height and overflow properties

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, css-calc

I am trying to make a div with a `height: calc(100% - 80px)` and an `overflow: scroll`. The div is completely ignoring both of these rules. Here is what I have attempted:

```css
.tab-content {
    clear: both;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    overflow: auto;
}

#tutorial {
    padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
Tutorial

<div id="tutorial" class="tab-content">
    Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
</div>
```

Please alert me of where I am going wrong and how to fix the problem.

Comment: `calc(100% - 80px);` there won't be overflow, how could you scroll?

Comment: @DanielH the content might overflow the div, that's when there would be scroll.

Comment: it is already working? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/h6Lam4rr/

Comment: @DanielH you have missed the point of the question.... read the spec...

Comment: by 100% do you mean the parent's height? or 100% of current window height?

Comment: @DanielH window height, like your answer that is correct

Comment: Cool =D glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be you want make the div `100% - 80px` the current window height. For that, you might use `100vh`

```css
.tab-content {
    clear: both;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    overflow: auto;
    background: aqua;
}

#tutorial {
    padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
Tutorial

<div id="tutorial" class="tab-content">
    Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
    <br> Tutorial content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you're running into is that the html and body tags are being automatically sized to the height of their content. If you want to implement a scroll bar on the internal div, you have to establish an overflow, otherwise there is no overflow.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.tab-content {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  clear: both;
  height: 100px;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 80px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 80px);
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  overflow: scroll;
}

#tutorial {
  padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
Tutorial

<div id="tutorial" class="tab-content">
  Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
  <br> Tutorial content
</div>
```